# Webrowser - waiting for document load

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous

I want to create method which will wait until document is't loaded.

I have something like that:

```
WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
MyClient client = new MyClient(webBrowser);
client.LogIn("test", "omg"); //block thread
client.NotImplemented(); //i'm already logged;

class MyClient
{    
    bool Started;
    WebBrowser webBrowser;

    public MyClient(WebBrowser wb)
    {
        webBrowser = wb;    
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Url == webBrowser.Url)
            {
                Started = false; //page loaded
            }
        };
    }

    public void LogIn(string login, string password)
    {
         this.Navigate("mymagicsite.com");
    }

    private void Navigate(string url)
    {
         webBrowser.Navigate(url);
         Started = true;

         while(Started)
             Task.Delay(50);
    }
}
```

And when I will be call LogIn method I want to "block" my thread.
Problem is in `Task.Delay`, it's blocking Navigate and nothing happens.

Comment: I don't get it -- what exactly are you asking with your code example above?  What problem are you having?

Comment: The problem is that webBrowser.Navigate() don't block thread (i want something like webClient.DownloadString("www.google.pl") - it's blocking current thread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TaskCompletionSource` to send an `async`-compatible "notification" of some event.

Like this:

```
class MyClient
{    
  TaskCompletionSource<object> navigation;
  WebBrowser webBrowser;

  public MyClient(WebBrowser wb)
  {
    navigation = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    webBrowser = wb;    
    webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
      if (e.Url == webBrowser.Url)
      {
        navigation.TrySetCompleted(null);
      }
    };
  }

  public Task LogIn(string login, string password)
  {
    navigation = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    webBrowser.Navigate(url);
    return navigation.Task;
  }
}
```

Which can be used as such:

```
WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
MyClient client = new MyClient(webBrowser);
await client.LogIn("test", "omg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to leave the UI thread going like and Disable the form and Enable once loading is done

*Usage*

```
MyClient client = new MyClient(webBrowser, 
            () => {  client.NotImplemented(); //i'm already logged; } 
          );
client.LogIn("test", "omg"); //block thread
```

*Implemation*

```
class MyClient
{    
    Form frm;

    public MyClient(WebBrowser wb, MethodInvoker callback)
    {
        frm = (Form) wb.Parent;  // assume WebBrowser is directly on the form
        webBrowser = wb;    
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
           frm.Invoke( new MethodInvoker( () => frm.Enabled = true ));   
           frm.Invoke(callback);      
        };
     }

    private void Navigate(string url)
    {
         webBrowser.Navigate(url);
         frm.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working. I don't know why but DocumentCompleted event isn't even fire...

Comment: If you use fiddler do you see the naviagtion take place? If you remove the if (e.Url == ...) line does it work then?

Comment: I was trying this simple code:  webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.pl");

            while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Task.Delay(50);
            } 
But ReadyState is Uninitialized all the time.
It seems that Navigate is working on UI thread, and when i'm blocking this thread the navigation isn't runnig - strage.

Comment: as you need to have the UI thread going I have updated my awswer